# JSONのレスポンスを格納したい

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

### やりたいこと

JSONのレスポンスをStructにCodableを使いまとめてTableViewにString型として表示したい。

### 疑問点&エラー

```
var movies = MovieStruct() Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call(insert 'from' <#Decoder#>)
```

と表示されます。元々は

```
var movies = [MovieStruct]()
```

上記のように配列に入れていたのですがAPIのRequestしたところ配列(辞書型？)にはなっておらず全て{}で返ってきていたため
上手く表示されておらずdecodeも配列で返すのを直したのですがmoviesに構造体からきたデータを格納したいのですが
記述の仕方があまりよく分からず。調べても配列で返ってきているAPIの物ばかりなので質問しました。

### ソースコード

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
//https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=

    @IBOutlet weak var movieTableView: UITableView!
    
    var movies = MovieStruct()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        fechData()
    }
    
    func fechData(){

        let url = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=")!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")
                return
            }
            
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            
            if let movies = try? decoder.decode(MovieStruct.self, from: data){
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                    self.movies = movies
                    self.movies.append(movies)
                    self.movieTableView.reloadData()
                }
            }else{
                print("Unable parse JSON response")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

extension ViewController:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return movies.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let movie = movies[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = movie.title
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = movie.release_date
        
        return cell
    }
}

struct MovieStruct: Codable {
    var title: String
    var release_date:String
}
```

### レスポンス

```
{
    adult = 0;
    "backdrop_path" = "/8iVyhmjzUbvAGppkdCZPiyEHSoF.jpg";
    "belongs_to_collection" = "<null>";
    budget = 63000000;
    genres =     (
                {
            id = 18;
            name = Drama;
        }
    );
    homepage = "http://www.foxmovies.com/movies/fight-club";
    id = 550;
    "imdb_id" = tt0137523;
    "original_language" = en;
    "original_title" = "Fight Club";
    overview = "A ticking-time-bomb insomniac and a slippery soap salesman channel primal male aggression into a shocking new form of therapy. Their concept catches on, with underground \"fight clubs\" forming in every town, until an eccentric gets in the way and ignites an out-of-control spiral toward oblivion.";
    popularity = "39.218";
    "poster_path" = "/wR5HZWdVpcXx9sevV1bQi7rP4op.jpg";
    "production_companies" =     (
                {
            id = 508;
            "logo_path" = "/7PzJdsLGlR7oW4J0J5Xcd0pHGRg.png";
            name = "Regency Enterprises";
            "origin_country" = US;
        },
                {
            id = 711;
            "logo_path" = "/tEiIH5QesdheJmDAqQwvtN60727.png";
            name = "Fox 2000 Pictures";
            "origin_country" = US;
        },
                {
            id = 20555;
            "logo_path" = "/hD8yEGUBlHOcfHYbujp71vD8gZp.png";
            name = "Taurus Film";
            "origin_country" = DE;
        },
                {
            id = 54051;
            "logo_path" = "<null>";
            name = "Atman Entertainment";
            "origin_country" = "";
        },
                {
            id = 54052;
            "logo_path" = "<null>";
            name = "Knickerbocker Films";
            "origin_country" = US;
        },
                {
            id = 25;
            "logo_path" = "/qZCc1lty5FzX30aOCVRBLzaVmcp.png";
            name = "20th Century Fox";
            "origin_country" = US;
        },
                {
            id = 4700;
            "logo_path" = "/A32wmjrs9Psf4zw0uaixF0GXfxq.png";
            name = "The Linson Company";
            "origin_country" = "";
        }
    );
    "production_countries" =     (
                {
            "iso_3166_1" = DE;
            name = Germany;
        },
                {
            "iso_3166_1" = US;
            name = "United States of America";
        }
    );
    "release_date" = "1999-10-15";
    revenue = 100853753;
    runtime = 139;
    "spoken_languages" =     (
                {
            "iso_639_1" = en;
            name = English;
        }
    );
    status = Released;
    tagline = "Mischief. Mayhem. Soap.";
    title = "Fight Club";
    video = 0;
    "vote_average" = "8.4";
    "vote_count" = 19688;
}
```

Comment: api_key につきまして、編集によって削除いただきましたが依然として編集履歴からは閲覧できる状態になっています。以下 2 点のご対応をいただきたいです。(1) key を revoke できるのであれば行い、他者がアクセスできないようにする。 (2) もし編集履歴からも除くことが必要であれば、[お問い合わせ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/contact)から「その他」扱いで編集履歴からの削除リクエストを出す。詳しくはこちらのヘルプをご覧ください: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3004/19110

Answer (score 2):

まず最初に、あなたが「レスポンス」として示されたのは実際のレスポンスではありません。どなたかが作られたプログラムで、レスポンスを`NSDictionary`で読み込んだ後に、その`NSDictionary`をを`print`などの形で出力したものと思われます。全く役に立たないわけではありませんが、元のJSONを完全には復元できないので、正しい回答を得るのには支障となる場合が多いです。

実際にレスポンスを取得して整形したものをお示ししておきます。

```
{
    "adult": false,
    "backdrop_path": "/8iVyhmjzUbvAGppkdCZPiyEHSoF.jpg",
    "belongs_to_collection": null,
    "budget": 63000000,
    "genres": [
        {
            "id": 18,
            "name": "Drama"
        }
    ],
    "homepage": "http://www.foxmovies.com/movies/fight-club",
    "id": 550,
    "imdb_id": "tt0137523",
    "original_language": "en",
    "original_title": "Fight Club",
    "overview": "A ticking-time-bomb insomniac and a slippery soap salesman channel primal male aggression into a shocking new form of therapy. Their concept catches on, with underground \"fight clubs\" forming in every town, until an eccentric gets in the way and ignites an out-of-control spiral toward oblivion.",
    "popularity": 34.634,
    "poster_path": "/wR5HZWdVpcXx9sevV1bQi7rP4op.jpg",
    "production_companies": [
        {
            "id": 508,
            "logo_path": "/7PzJdsLGlR7oW4J0J5Xcd0pHGRg.png",
            "name": "Regency Enterprises",
            "origin_country": "US"
        },
        {
            "id": 711,
            "logo_path": "/tEiIH5QesdheJmDAqQwvtN60727.png",
            "name": "Fox 2000 Pictures",
            "origin_country": "US"
        },
        {
            "id": 20555,
            "logo_path": "/hD8yEGUBlHOcfHYbujp71vD8gZp.png",
            "name": "Taurus Film",
            "origin_country": "DE"
        },
        {
            "id": 54051,
            "logo_path": null,
            "name": "Atman Entertainment",
            "origin_country": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 54052,
            "logo_path": null,
            "name": "Knickerbocker Films",
            "origin_country": "US"
        },
        {
            "id": 25,
            "logo_path": "/qZCc1lty5FzX30aOCVRBLzaVmcp.png",
            "name": "20th Century Fox",
            "origin_country": "US"
        },
        {
            "id": 4700,
            "logo_path": "/A32wmjrs9Psf4zw0uaixF0GXfxq.png",
            "name": "The Linson Company",
            "origin_country": ""
        }
    ],
    "production_countries": [
        {
            "iso_3166_1": "DE",
            "name": "Germany"
        },
        {
            "iso_3166_1": "US",
            "name": "United States of America"
        }
    ],
    "release_date": "1999-10-15",
    "revenue": 100853753,
    "runtime": 139,
    "spoken_languages": [
        {
            "iso_639_1": "en",
            "name": "English"
        }
    ],
    "status": "Released",
    "tagline": "Mischief. Mayhem. Soap.",
    "title": "Fight Club",
    "video": false,
    "vote_average": 8.4,
    "vote_count": 19690
}
```

**このレスポンスはJSON objectになっているため、このレスポンスに`decode(_:from:)`を呼ぶだけでは決して配列を結果として得ることはできません**。

そもそも、このレスポンス、(元の`NSDictionary`形式のままでも)中身をよくチェックすればわかりますが、映画1本分の情報しかありません。したがって「TableViewに...表示したい」と言う部分が意味を為しません。

---

あなたはこのTableViewに本当は何を表示したいのでしょうか?

#### TableViewの各行が映画1本を表示するようにしたい

⇒ 複数の映画情報を取得できるようなAPIを調べてそれを呼んでください。

#### TableViewが映画1本の中に複数存在する情報を1行ずつ表示するようにしたい

⇒ 一体自分は何の情報を表示したいのか調べてください。

#### 映画1本分の情報を1つの画面に表示したい

⇒ TableViewを使わずに画面デザインをしてください

---

自分が呼び出しているAPIがどのような情報を返してくるのか、全く理解せずに使っておられるように見えます。学校か新人研修の課題なんでしょうか?

一体本来は何をしたいのかがもう少しわかれば、何か回答できる内容が増えるかもしれません。

Comment: TableViewの各行が映画1本を表示するようにしたい。が自分のやりたい事です。APIの管理の甘さすみません。おっしゃる通りよく見てみるとRequestの例を使っていて1本分しか取れていませんでした。NSDictionaryを使い取り出したとありますが、本来ならば何を使ってレスポンスを取得しているのですかね？

Comment: @uta さん、だとすると「複数の映画情報を取得できるようなAPI」を使用してもらわないといけないですね。「NSDictionaryを使い取り出した」のには、`JSONSerialization`を使われたのでしょう。`Codable`が導入されて以降はどんどん使われなくなっているものですが、これを使うと結果が`NSArray`または`NSDictionary`で得られます。「これが実際のJSONレスポンス」と言うべきものを取得したい場合には、`JSONSerialization`や`JSONDecoder`を使う前に`data`の内容をテキストに変換します。

Comment: JSONSerializationを確かに使いました。確認したところAPIのレスポンスをそのサイト内だけで取得できるように元から設定されており、クエリを入力すると取得できる形でした。APIの仕様がまだあまり分からずどれが全てのデータを取得できる方法なのかは分かっていませんが、レスポンスの取得方法が自分の想像と違っていた事が分かりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @uta さん、返信ありがとうございます。正直言うと「APIのレスポンスをそのサイト内だけで取得できるように元から設定されており、クエリを入力すると取得できる」「レスポンスの取得方法が自分の想像と違っていた」と言うのが何を表すのかがよくわからないのですが、ご質問文を編集して何かしら具体的な情報を追記していただければ、何かお手伝いできることもあるかもしれません。よろしければご質問への情報の追記をお願いします。